# jQuery get the element parent and call the slideToggle function

Tags: jquery

I need some help with jquery. How to get the `.content` after I click on the `.slider` ? I want then to call the `.slideToggle()` function

```
<div class='details'>
    <div>
       <a href='#' class='slider'>my link</a>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
       some content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you clarify your question a bit more? how do you mean get the .content after you click? do you want to show the content of it when clicked? what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do either of these

```
$(".details a.slider").click(function(){

    $(this).parent().children(".content").slideToggle();

});
```

or (think this should work too)

```
$(".details a.slider").click(function(){

    $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: the .siblings() function wokrs too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $('.slider').click(function(e) {
      $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle();
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: `.preventDefault()` should be the _first_ item in the function, not the last.

Comment: @Sparky672 I don't think that will make the slightest bit of difference to this code.

Comment: If you say so.  However, [placing it first is the documented way](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to use it.

Comment: @Sparky672 this may be useful: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/#top_bottom_or_somewhere_in_the_middle

Answer (score 0):

OK I've figured it out

```
 $(this).closest('div.details').children('div.content').slideToggle();
```

Comment: i would have used siblings over that I think - think that should work anyway

Answer (score -1):

if I'm understanding you correctly, you want something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.slider').click(function() {
        $('.content').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: if he had multiple instances of the html he wants to toggle then this would toggle them all and not the one currently being focused on by the user.